# How do I convert character encodings with Javascript? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

Ive got this in an XML file that i parse with JQuery.

```
<title>L&#229;ng</title>
```

I'm using .text() for pulling out the text, but it's wrong encoded.
How do I get it encoded to proper text? I want 'Lång' out of it.

Edit:

I'm using JQuery for getting data. Have it on my work computer, but something like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'http://myserver/blah?query_string',
 dataType: 'xml',
 success: function(data) {
   var blah = $(this).find("blahblah").text(); 
 }
});
```

Comment: entities will be displayed fine in the browser, so why you need that?

Comment: Because I need to do comparing of results.

Comment: Can you show us how you're getting the XML data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it! 
[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

Using this function solved all enocoding problems.

```
function htmlDecode(value){ 
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the characters are always encoded to numbers like that, you should be able to parse out the number, convert it to and integer with `parseInt(str)` then use `string.fromCharCode(num)` to get the character that it represents.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should just switch to utf-8. All ajax request are utf-8 by default. This might fix the problem.